# How do i reset these values to 0?

Tags: jquery, html, css

The code of the button/input:

```
<div class="input-group input-number-group">
    <div class="input-group-button">
        <span class="input-number-decrement">-</span>
    </div>
         <input class="input-number" max="10" min="0" value="0">
             <div class="input-group-button">
                 <span class="input-number-increment">+</span>
             </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Image: [image]

So i read i need to use button type="reset",
But that doesn't work.

Comment: Do you mean `javascript` instead of `java`?

Comment: Where is the reset button ?

Comment: I did not put it in because it doesn't work any way i did it. So thought maybe some people had tips and tricks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<input type="reset">` needs to be used inside a `<form>` tag. Otherwise how can 'it' know what to reset?

Like `<input type="submit">` which submits the form, `<input type="reset">` clears all values from the form. So without javascript you can use the reset input if you wrap the number input ( which is a text input ) and the reset input inside a form. See below

```html
<form>
  <div class="input-group input-number-group">
    <div class="input-group-button">
      <span class="input-number-decrement">-</span>
    </div>
    <input class="input-number" max="10" min="0" value="0">
    <div class="input-group-button">
      <span class="input-number-increment">+</span>
    </div>
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
  </div>
</form>
```

If you do not want to use a form, then you would need javascript ( which has nothing to do with `java` . so do not tag it )

Simple examples below with jQuery and plain javaScript.

```js
//jQuery
const btn = $('.jquery')
const numberInput = $('.input-number')
btn.on('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(numberInput).val(0)
})

//plain javaScript

const button = document.querySelector('.javascript')
const number = document.querySelector('.input-number')
button.onclick = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  number.value = 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group input-number-group">
  <div class="input-group-button">
    <span class="input-number-decrement">-</span>
  </div>
  <input class="input-number" max="10" min="0" value="0">
  <div class="input-group-button">
    <span class="input-number-increment">+</span>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="jquery">
reset with jQuery
</button>
<button class="javascript">
reset with plain javaScript
</button>
```

PS i assume you have the code for the increment and decrement buttons. As your question is only about the reset.

PS2 i used `preventDefault()` because of the ' better safe than sorry ' motto :)